# Rails 4: How to save a file to a server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, ruby-on-rails-4, upload

How do I create an empty HTML File and then save it to the server via carrierwave in Rails 4?

Here is what I tried:

```
file = File.new("abc.html", 'w')
@upload = Upload.create(name: "abc", file: FileUploader.new.store!(file))
```

Upload Model:

```
mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
```

What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: Why do you need CarrieWave to do so? Rails is running server-side and if you create a file it will be store in the server anyway.

Comment: @Ed de Almeida Where does Rails store that file?

Comment: It's because I want to store that file on cloudinary and not on my server. I then have to delete the file on my server after i uploaded it.

Comment: Wherever you want! Set the file name like `"#{Rails.root.join('my','directory','path')}/abc.html"` and it wilt be `<your_app_path>/my/directory/path/abc.html`.

Comment: But back to the question how do I upload it with carrierwave because I really don't want that file on my server

Comment: And where do you intend it to be after you upload it from the client? Google Drive? AWS?

Comment: Ah! Got it! You want to create it in your server and then store it somewhere else and delete it from your server, isn't it?

Comment: That's right! My problem is the process of uploading it to the server via carrierwave. (I am using carrierwave just to upload data to my cloudinary server)

Comment: I never used cloudinary, but since the file is an empty file, I believe there is a way to create it directly there and avoid this step of uploading. Consider using this [Cloudinary gem](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem) here.

Comment: The actual server (cloudinary) is not important. Important is just the general step of uploading a file via carrierwave.  And that's what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The way I am doing it, I get the error `undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass` in my CarrierWave Uploader

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130345/discussion-between-ed-de-almeida-and-jonhue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
class Upload
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end

@upload = Upload.new
@upload.file = File.new("abc.html", 'w')
@upload.save!
```

Comment: Works. Thank you!